# How do you do advance shell scripting for FIFO and Clock Policy to calculate page fault?

Tags: linux, bash, page-fault

I am new to bash shell scripting. I know how to calculate the page fault manually for both but i have no idea how to do it using advance shell scripting. If anyone got the time to teach or even give me an example for both of it, i will be really grateful. Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: /usr/bin/time -v /path/to/executable - will report page faults (major and minor), etc. when process is complete

Comment: Thank you so much.